# Android add and divide at the same time

Tags: java, android

You only enter one integer or decimal in the TextView.

Let's say you enter 5 and click enter it should do the calculations and display the result.

I'm new to Java and Android.
I'm new to Java and Android.
I'm new to Java and Android.
I'm new to Java and Android.

Comment: okay Corey, you have a textbox, this textbox has a method which is called textbox.getText(), you can get your value out of this, then you can use it in an calculation, which gives a result, and has to be saved to a new variable. what is your actual problem?

Comment: No, Corey. A text is only a writing. It doesn't magically become a math equation only because YOU see it as such. You must tell the CPU to handle it.

Comment: What is the variable **average_bg** declared as? Is it getting its data from the text box? Here's a thought perhaps: `double average_bg = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText()); double ac = (2.59 + average_bg) / 1.59;` or something to that nature :)

Comment: You're welcome Corey :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextView` is read only - use `EditText` instead.

1. Set EditText to digits only:

   ```
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
   ```
2. Set `onKeyListener` to listen for "Enter" press and call calculation:

   ```
   editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
               if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && 
                   (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                   // Perform your calculation on key press and update edit text
                   editText.setText(String.valueOf(doCalc(
                       Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString())));

                   return true;
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
   ```
3. Create method for calculation:

   ```
   private double doCalc(double average_bg) {
       return (2.59 + average_bg) / 1.59;
   }
   ```